# computing 2 column of a table and updating the third column based on distinct value of a table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update tbl_addemployee set 
amount_due=amount_due+((tsalary/30)*187),
com_salary_date='2016-11-04' 
where (forUser='sun4269' and E_id)
```

i want to update com_salary_date for each distinct record where forUser='sun4269'
and the distinct column name is E_id

Comment: so what is the problem? show us sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join matching distinct records using an INNER JOIN

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.amount_due = amount_due+((tsalary/30)*187),
    T.com_salary_date = '2016-11-04' 
FROM
    tbl_addemployee  AS T
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
           forUser, 
           E_id 
         FROM 
           tbl_addemployee
    )  AS X
    ON X.forUser=T.forUser AND X.E_id=T.E_id
```